# Wikidata SPARQL select a website in the language of English

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I am trying to write a query for Wikidata that selects the official website (P856) for Johnson & Johnson (Q333718) where the language (P407) is English (Q1860).

```
SELECT ?website WHERE {
  wd:Q333718 wdt:P856 ?website.
  ?website p:P407 wd:Q1860
}
```

[This query](https://w.wiki/5VQQ) does not return anything.

Comment: `SELECT ?website WHERE {
  wd:Q333718 p:P856 [ps:P856 ?website ; pq:P407 wd:Q1860]
}`

Comment: Thanks - would you make this an answer so that I can mark it as answered?

Comment: @UninformedUser Thanks again.  I modified the query to try a few different companies: 

SELECT ?website WHERE {
   VALUES ?item {
    wd:Q483551
    wd:Q2283
    wd:Q192314
    wd:Q2103926
    wd:Q37156
    wd:Q333718
  }
  ?item p:P856 _:b1.
  _:b1 ps:P856 ?website;
    pq:P407 wd:Q1860;
    rdf:type wikibase:BestRank
}

But I don't believe this is guaranteed to just return one row per company, because a company could have more than one official website in English, and they could both/all be at the best rank. How do you ensure one result per comp. - is sample the best bet?